# Tests fail when device screen is sleeping

Tags: android, adb, calabash, calabash-android

I am trying to run some Calabash tests on an Android device. If I manually turn the screen before running the tests then everything works. On a Nexus 4 if I turn the screen off and try to run the tests then my first scenario times out waiting for elements to appear. On a Galaxy Nexus if I start the tests with the screen off then Calabash wakes up the device and the tests pass.

Are there some devices that Calabash simply cannot wake up? Is the Nexus 4 one of these? Turning on the devices manually is not feasible since I will run these tests frequently on many devices.

I have found some outdated references to this issue. A post from 2012 by Adam Niedzielski at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/calabash-android/o6lUuEOuGtE suggests the following hook in `app_life_cycle_hooks.rb`

```
include Calabash::Android::Operations

AfterConfiguration do |config|
  wake_up
end
```

but code was added to `ruby-gem/bin/calabash-android` in Calabash that explicitly disallows inclusion of the `Operations` module: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/commit/995daef9b6636e7e4e572aeb5d4f90d6d072320f so I guess this is no longer the recommended approach. If I remove the include and just type `Calabash::Android::Operations.wake_up` I get a `NameError`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into this error occasionally and ended up setting the screen timeout to longer than a minute and running this method before starting the tests:

```
  def self.turn_on_screen(device_serial_number)
    # Switches on the android devices screen if it isn’t already on.
    if `adb -s #{device_serial_number} shell dumpsys input_method | grep mScreenOn`.include? 'false'
      `adb -s #{device_serial_number} shell input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER`
    end
  end
```

This will turn simulate a keypress of the power button if the screen isn't already on.  I've used this on about 4 different devices and not had any issues so far so hopefully it'll work for you.

It may be worth noting that I've also turned lockscreens off the the devices.

EDIT: After an update to lollipop I had to add in another check.  Using both seems to do the trick on all of my test devices.

```
if `adb shell dumpsys input_method | grep mInteractive`.include? 'false'
  `adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER`
end
```

Comment: Nice workaround! I didn't think of using adb. I think this will do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: on a galaxy S3, I had to do `adb shell input keyevent 66` instead of `KEYCODE_POWER`

Comment: I had a related issue on HTC M8: in my case the screen does not turn off, but dims instead, which causes the first touch event in the tests to be lost (it just undims the screen and never gets to the app). Adding the following code to app_life_cycle_hooks.rb after start_test_server_in_background helped:
    `system("#{default_device.adb_command} shell input keyevent KEYCODE_UNKNOWN")`